# Using Utl_mail package to send email on Oracle 10g grid

Tags: oracle10g

Can somebody please advice using special character in message body is allowed or not? I am using a word "month's" in the nessage body but it is getting replaced by "month?s" in the email. Please HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MS Word to edit your code :)

Most probably, your editor is replacing the ' with a special left- or right-pointing apostrophe.

Try copying the code into a "plain" text editor (Notepad would do fine) and re-type the ' in the code, then recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You can email special characters, in the Subject and the Body.

```
BEGIN
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'me@domain.com',
                recipients => 'you@domain.com',
                subject    => 'Cards? ♠♥♦♣',
                message    => 'Shall we play cards? ♠♥♦♣');
END;
/
```

If the special characters are being replaced by "?" then either the database or the email recipient does not have a UTF8 charcaterset